# Making a tuple from another tuple with more than one condition in one line in python

Tags: python, coding-style, iteration, tuples, code-snippets

As we have a syntax like below in python:

```
for i in range(10):
     print 'Hello!' if i % 3 == 0 else 'Waiting' if i % 3 == 1 else 'Bye!'
```

that will make output like this:

```
Hello!
Waiting
Bye!
Hello!
Waiting
Bye!
Hello!
Waiting
Bye!
Hello!
```

and also we have this too:

```
a = tuple('a member' for i in range(10) if i % 3 == 0)
```

that makes a tuple like `('a member', 'a member', 'a member', 'a member')`

now I want to know is there anything like:

`a = tuple('a member' for i in range(10) if i % 3 == 0 else 'another member')` ?

because when I add the `else 'another member'` it fails with SyntaxError Exception

here is the python console output:

```
>>> a = tuple('a member' for i in range(10) if i % 3 == 0 else 'another member')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a = tuple('a member' for i in range(10) if i % 3 == 0 else 'another member')
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

(I exactly want to write just one line that do sth like:

```
a = tuple('Hello!' for i in range(10) if i % 3 == 0 else 'Waiting' if i % 3 == 1 else 'Bye!')
```

and leave me a tuple which its members are the lines in the first example

Also there is no matter the code is in python 2 or 3 since I could work with both to do my job ;) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (you have to bring your conditions before the `for` statement):

```
tuple('Hello!' if i % 3 == 0 else 'Waiting' if i % 3 == 1 else 'Bye!' for i in range(10))
```

A bit clearer, using `itertools`:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice
tuple(islice(cycle(('Hello!', 'Waiting', 'Bye!')), 10))
```

Comment: this is the very thing that I want! so simple that I got the point just with the first read and also exactly let me have the correct code! TnX so MUCH! :D

Comment: @ARF my pleasure! that's the beauty of Python's syntax - it reads just as clear as pseudo-code

Comment: the second one is also a good thing! I did not heared about 'itertools' but it seems it is so useful! and also yes! the python simplicity leads to a language that is VERY readable even by childs and newbies! Also TnX again for the second code you provided! ;)

Answer (score 0):

In a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) or generator expression when modifying the data the conditions are placed on the left side, for filtering items place the conditions on the right side:

```
>>> tuple('Hello!' if i % 3 == 0 else 'Waiting' if i % 3 == 1 else 'Bye!' 
                                                      for i in xrange(10))
('Hello!', 'Waiting', 'Bye!', 'Hello!', 'Waiting', 'Bye!', 'Hello!', 'Waiting', 'Bye!', 'Hello!')
```

Readable versions of the above code:

```
>>> lis  = ['Hello!', 'Waiting' ,'Bye!']
>>> tuple( lis[i%3] for i in xrange(10) )
('Hello!', 'Waiting', 'Bye!', 'Hello!', 'Waiting', 'Bye!', 'Hello!', 'Waiting', 'Bye!', 'Hello!')
#or
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> cyc = cycle(lis)
>>> tuple(next(cyc) for _ in xrange(10))
('Hello!', 'Waiting', 'Bye!', 'Hello!', 'Waiting', 'Bye!', 'Hello!', 'Waiting', 'Bye!', 'Hello!')
```

Comment: so Y we have `i for i in (sth) if someCondition` also?? because I tested it in py2 and 3 both and the syntax works but py3 philosophy tells we want to make a language that to do things there be one and exactly one way to do it?? :confused!

Comment: and also +1 for second form (even it's not in one line and I will not go that way! ;))

Comment: @ARF `i for i in (sth) if someCondition` is similar to `filter` built-in function, i.e `i` is placed in the list only if the condition is `True`.
While something like `i**2 if i%2 ==0 else i for i in (sth)` is equivalent to `map` built-in function, Here we use the modified value of `i` based on the condition.

Comment: @ARF And py2 and py3 don't have different philosophies.

Comment: forgive me! I mixed up python and perl! :zZ and also I told tanks to our explanation on the reason that we should move our if statement before for statement and also thanks again to remember me that the philosophy is same. also I'm slow typist (20 wpm) so please don't think that I want to insult! ;)

Answer (score 0):

for this specific application:

```
tuple( ['Hello', 'Waiting', 'Bye!'][ i % 3] for i in range (0, 10))
```

since it's just lookup problem.  Even though list comprehensions are awesome, though, multiple chained if-elses in a single line strikes me as very unpythonic. To quote [Pep 20:](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

> Explicit is better than implicit.  Simple is better than complex.

In any but the most trivial case I'd do something like:

```
expr = lambda a : some_complex_way_of_evaluating(a)
result = tuple ( expr(a) for a in range(0,10)
```

So that the  list comp syntax, the range syntax and the evaluation expressions were not all competing for attention in one line

Comment: clever way to use the modulo by 3 as index! I do these things before in C++ and Java but I want to understand any syntax to do these things with if-else statements :D It's the fun of programming and also the fun of python that you could write a line to do sth which their equivalents in other languages of another idea could lead to even 20-30 lines of code! Also TnX for your beautiful answer using modulo! :)

Comment: The classic pythonic way to do elif style fallthrough would be more like  ( {0:'Hello', 1:'Waiting', 2:'Bye'}[i%3] for i in range (0,10)). Dictionaries are a base type in python so its very common to use them as the equivalent of switch/case or elif chains in other languages

Comment: thank you as you mentioned dictionaries. they're good things! I <3 them! ;) :D